# Create a Multidimensional Array with Codeigniter and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I'm developing internal mailing system using codeigniter, everything done perfetcly like gmail mailing system, except reply.

here i want to show replied message and current message both in single mail(if the mail is replied) like gmail.

Lets say i have threads table, that has a one to many relationship with table messages.

**threads**

> thread_id | msg_id | sender_id | sender_role | receiver_id |
>   receiver_role | status

**messages**

> id | subject | body | cdate

Above tables working fine for showing inbox and sent mails.

But now i want to show replied message also along with original message.(like gmail).

for this i'm planning to change the structure of threads table(adding two more fields reply-0 or 1, reply_id)

> SELECT  `subject` ,  `body` ,  `cdate` ,  `sender_id` ,  `username` AS
>   email,  `lbs_mails`.`id` AS mail_id,  `status` ,  `sender_role` ,
>   thread_id FROM (  `lbs_mails` ) JOIN  `lbs_threads` ON 
>   `lbs_threads`.`msg_id` =  `lbs_mails`.`id`  JOIN  `lbs_auth` ON 
>   `lbs_auth`.`uid` =  `lbs_threads`.`sender_id`  AND role =
>   lbs_threads.sender_role WHERE  `lbs_threads`.`receiver_role` =  '3'
>   AND  `lbs_threads`.`receiver_id` =  '1'

An efficient way to retrieve data would be to create a multidimensional array such as:

```
$inbox = array(
            [subject] => reply to Test Mail
            [body] => reply to Test Mail
            [cdate] => 2014-04-22 17:56:42
            [sender_id] => 2
            [email] => email@email.com
            [mail_id] => 7
            [status] => 1
            [sender_role] => 2
            [reply_id] => array(
                [subject] => reply to Test Mail
                [body] => reply to Test Mail
                [cdate] => 2014-04-22 17:56:42
            )
        )
```

How can i achieve this, can anyone help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest option would be for you to make one database call for the message and then a second database call to retrieve associated reply data. Then simply look over the data and combine it into an array.